# Break point hangs DirectX-based program in full screen mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, directx, breakpoints

I started making a game, I have a global class that reads in a csv file, loads two direct x surfaces, and creates the background.

the surfaces are a tile sheet and the other the background created from the tiles. the background surface does no work, after instillation I check it and if null a message box appears. It always shows the message box.

I tried setting break points to see if the values are read in corectly fron the csv file but the program will not run. a box appears in the task bar, the program goes full screen but the screen goes black and does not show the message box and can only be stopped by ctrl,alt,del.

No matter were I put the break point even if it is in a different source file this happens. does anyone know why ?

p.s it is not a multi thread application.

Edit:

I am using visual studio 2005 and direct x 9.c

Comment: Also might be worth hitting 'step' instead of 'run', to see if you can step into the code that way

Comment: Full-screen mode "hijacks" the display from Windows.  Windows no longer can write things to the display without messing with DirectX.  Therefore, full-screen mode in DirectX is not recommended these days; it is much better to use Windowed-mode and just expand the window to the whole screen.  Windowed mode is only a little bit slower, so make sure you need that extra speed in full-screen mode.

Comment: Developers writing full-screen mode programs usually develop and debug first in Windowed-mode, or have another computer with a debugger linked remotely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With directshow, it can be bothering to debug in full screen : if you really have to do it, I suggest either using a second screen (this way, you can debug on your screen 1 while your program runs in full screen on your screen2).

If this doesn't work, you'll have to use remote debugging (i.e. run the programm on a computer and debug on another).

Most probably, what happens is that your debug point is triggerred, but your screen is held by directshow and thus visual can't be displayed. Thus your programm is actually blocked by visual, it doesn't answer to anything (as the event loop is blocked by the debugger)

In order, I would:

- run in windowed mode
- run in dual screen with your debugger on other screen
- try to setup remote debug (good luck)
- maybe use the old good way to debug with printf / traces (log4cpp e.g.)

Comment: would use printf but the error is that i cant get anything to show on screen but black lol hence the break point option. This is a really useful answer as I was confident in the direct x framework I developed and am using but thinking about it this is the first time I have tried a breakpoint in full screen.

Comment: I second the recommendation to use either two video cards and two monitors, or one video card capable of driving two monitors.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, if your project is not configured in debug mode (and instead is configured as release) you will not be able to debug, so any breakpoints you set will be ignored.  This could possibly be the problem.

Comment: It is in debug and if the break point was ignored why would the application freeze in start up?

Comment: It could freeze because the logic in your program is entering an infinite loop. This could also be the case prior to your breakpoint, which causes the descibed behavior. Have you tried setting a breakpoint near the beginning of your program and attemptiong to step through? I know it's tedious in a graphics program, but you may discover such a issue causing your screen to hang.
EDIT: Per the answer and information above, it seems like this likely isn't the case.  Sounds like @Bruce is on the right path. GL!

Answer (score 0):

forced it in windowed mode , you may modified or hook the application